# How to change date to the format of Mysql in Jsp?

Tags: jsp

In a Jsp I've got a input date String formatting as “Aug-6-2009”，how to change that to "2009-08-06" so that Mysql can read.

Maybe i need regex?

That may seem to be a easy question,but bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` object's `.parse()` and `.format()` methods to get a string in the format you need.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: java.text.DateFormat.parse() is preferred over deprecated java.util.Date.parse().

Comment: Already updated the answer to reflect that (SimpleDateFormat inherit's DateFormat's parse method).

Answer (score 0):

```
<%       
    String dateReceivedFromUser = request.getParameter("datepicker"); 
    DateFormat userDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");  
    DateFormat dateFormatNeeded = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");  
    Date date = userDateFormat.parse(dateReceivedFromUser);  
    String convertedDate = dateFormatNeeded.format(date);  
    System.out.println("Date is"+convertedDate);
    user.setDoj(convertedDate);
```

%>